# Getting incorrect output in C# when dividing two decimals

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mathematical-optimization, division

I have a program which divides a variable with another variable.
But the answer im getting is incorrect!!!
Please check image below :

[image: l]

Code Below:

```
      iter_defects++;
      df1[iter_defects].blob_id = b.Id;
      decimal convertX = Convert.ToDecimal(txtmmtopixX.Text);
      decimal convertY = Convert.ToDecimal(txtmmtopixY.Text);
      df1[iter_defects].count = iter_defects;

      df1[iter_defects].cog_X = Math.Round( Convert.ToDecimal( b.Centroid.X)) / convertX;
      df1[iter_defects].cog_Y = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(b.Centroid.Y ))/ convertY;
     if (df1[iter_defects].cog_X > 10 && df1[iter_defects].cog_X < 30)
      {

     if (df1[iter_defects].BY > 1 && df1[iter_defects].BY < 74)
      {
       df1[iter_defects].cog_X = df1[iter_defects].cog_X - 20;

       }

      if (df1[iter_defects].BY > 64 && df1[iter_defects].BY < 129)
        {
         df1[iter_defects].cog_X = df1[iter_defects].cog_X - 20;

         }

      if (df1[iter_defects].BY > 118 && df1[iter_defects].BY < 183)
         {
           df1[iter_defects].cog_X = df1[iter_defects].cog_X - 20;

         }

       }
```

b.centroid.X and b.centroid.Y are double by default, so im converting it to decimal.

If I divide 147 by 9.3 i should get approx 16, but im getting 7.9!

Earlier I was using double instead of decimal, but even decimal is giving same issues. Have pinned the variable values on the image on the right.

What could be wrong?

UPDATE:

In my nested if statement I so some more arithmetic operation based on few conditions. When I removed those conditions the calculation is happening just fine. More confused now. The code below works, but without those conditions, my code after this section wont work:

```
  iter_defects++;
  df1[iter_defects].blob_id = b.Id;
  decimal convertX = Convert.ToDecimal(txtmmtopixX.Text);
  decimal convertY = Convert.ToDecimal(txtmmtopixY.Text);
  df1[iter_defects].count = iter_defects;

  df1[iter_defects].cog_X = Math.Round( Convert.ToDecimal( b.Centroid.X)) / convertX;
  df1[iter_defects].cog_Y = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(b.Centroid.Y ))/ convertY;
 if (df1[iter_defects].cog_X > 10 && df1[iter_defects].cog_X < 30)
  {
  df1[iter_defects].cog_X = df1[iter_defects].cog_X - 20;
  }
```

Comment: DO NOT show code as image!!

Comment: I was showing the values the variables have, have pinned it on the right.

Comment: I know. Hard to read and useless when trying to reproduce..

Comment: 1) Post code as text not an image. 2) If it's incorrect, what would be correct?

Comment: Have updated code as text with image. 147 / 9.3 should be 16, im getting 7.9 in the program.

Comment: What is the `cog_X`, field or property? Do you have something specific in a setter? Is `iter_defects` remains unchanged during calculation?

Comment: cogX is decimal struct, iter_defects is an integer which increments in df1 array within foreach whenever a rejection is found. cog_X and cog_Y are coordinates of the rejected area in the image.

Comment: `decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)b.Centroid.X / convertX, MidpointRounding.ToEven);`. Or without `MidpointRounding.ToEven`, see what you need to get back.

Comment: @Jimi same thing happens with your suggestion.

Comment: Hi,  I have updated my question. I had few nested if statements below my code to do some mope operation, when i remove those statements, the  output is fine. Im confused as those nested if conditions are just to sort the X coordinate in sections.

Comment: When did you check the division result? Before or after that later code changed the result?

Comment: i created breakpoints on each of those nested if's to check the result.

Comment: I just copied the values you're showing in your question (the Image), to the last decimal. With those numbers, the result is 16. Also, you cannot have the same result with the code I posted, because I moved the division inside `Math.Round()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code does not show the types of the variables, you do not explain which item(s) are getting the wrong value(s).  There is a lot of code (in the first block) after the divisions, how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: Please read the link near the bottom of [mcve] about debugging small programs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how your program works, but I assume the problem is probably because you are in a loop of some kind and by the time you are checking your results, more than one iteration has occurred and the base values (ex `cog_X`) have changed, so your comparison math won't match.